# Could not find junit:junit:4.12 in Android Studio

Tags: android, junit, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

Im new to testing in android studio, im was trying to setup the gradle for adding dependencies for Junit4.

However, the gradle console informs me **"Could not find junit:junit:4.12."**

It seems like gradle search the dependency in local folder instead of via internet, please inform how I should setup the gradle file for adding the dependecy for Junit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is using a Gradle build and not the android maven plugin.

Comment: then how should I add junit dependency to android project in AS?

Comment: I dont know Gradle enough but from a first glance what you are doing it all seems correct.

Comment: I am also stuck with the same issue.You can avoid it by commenting testcompile : junit.But I havent find the solution /root cause for this issue so far.

Answer (score 2):

You need **internet connection** *-at least first time-* to build project first time correctly (i really don't know why) !!!

so, to avoid that you may try download JUnit (required library) from [here](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar) and add it manually to your application into ~[YourAppFolder]\app\libs

then **rebuild** your app.

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out `//testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`.

This will solve the problem if you don't have internet access as you run app after installing Android Studio. As soon as you have internet access, uncomment and run your app, there after everything remains fixed won't be needing internet access again.

I'm sure it works. Not sure why, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have in your build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

The above will fetch the plugin `com.android.application`. That's all it will do.

You should have the below to fetch all your `dependencies`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```